# SP2013 Master Page changes are not being applied

Tags: 2013, master-page, refresh

I make changes to the markup of a master page (HTML version of course), convert it - successfully, can verify that the true .MASTER page has also been changed).

However, when I then render any page that uses this master page, I see that the changes are NOT reflected (e.g. the markup changes I made are missing).

I've tried several different tactics, including iisreset. Nothing works reliably.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Have you published a major version of the .master file?

Comment: Are you using publishing site?

Comment: How are you deploying your new master page? Using wsp or sharepoint designer?

Comment: Yes, it's a publishing site; 
Yes, I've published several major versions of the .master file.
I'm actually using Dreamweaver, but Sharepoint Designer is a reasonable mental substitute.

Comment: I misspoke -- it turned out to be a page layout that wouldn't convert. It finally did, if I saved it by using Sharepoint Designer (see below).

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think saving a HTML file in Dreamweaver will update the .master. If you use SPD, it will automatically make the changes to the .MASTER once you save your HTML. If for some reason this doesn't work, go to design manager => Edit Master Pages and create a fresh one from the HTML file and just delete the old one:

```
"/_layouts/15/DesignMasterPages.aspx"
```

Comment: Colbs, you're right -- sort of. Copying the file into place using the file system seems to work only for master pages. For Page Layouts (that's where the markup turned out to be), editing the .html file in SPD and saving it seemed to do the trick.

Thumbs-up!

Comment: Gotcha, good to go. Glad you figured it out +1

Answer (score 0):

On a page layout, sharepoint designer seems to be the only vehicle that guarantees success.

Answer (score 0):

I had this recently and the problem was my local DNS going a bit mad.

The site was at `//site_location/` but for me to get to it/open in SharePoint designer I had to go to `//site_location.domain.co.uk` so whilst it opened fine and I could do most things, when it tried to update it was looking for `//site_location` (which it couldn't find) so wouldn't update the .master file.

I added the IP and hostname to my hosts file, reopened the site with `//site_location` and everything worked.